# Textbox not showing on page

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I am trying to show a textbox after selecting an item from a populated listbox and clicking a button.
After I click the button, the textbox should show up on the screen with the desired text however it never appears. The initial value of the visible property is set to false, then in the Code Behind it sets it to true and fills the text in the textbox. I debugged the code and the properties for visible and text are definitely being updated, but I don't know what the problem is.

ASP.net

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormSectionFormView" runat="server" DataKeyNames="FormSectionID" DataSourceID="FormSectionDataSource" RowStyle-VerticalAlign="NotSet">
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="InsertButton"
            runat="server"
            Text="Insert" 
            OnClick="FormSectionButton_Click" 
            Font-Size="1.2em" />
            <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton"
            runat="server"
            Text="Update"
            Font-Size="1.2em"/>              
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <div style: align="center">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1"
                runat="server"
                Font-Bold="true"
                Text="Section Instruction"
                Font-Size="1.2em">
                    </asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div style="width:800px; height:auto; overflow:auto">
                <asp:ListBox ID="SectionInstructionListBox"
                DataSourceID="SectionInstructionSource"
                runat="server"
                DataTextField="Instruction"
                Visible="True" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div style="padding-top: 4em; width:800px">
                <asp:Label ID="Label5"
                runat="server"
                Font-Bold="true"
                Text="Insert New Instruction"
                Font-Size="1.2em">
                </asp:Label>              
                <asp:TextBox ID="SectionInstructionTextBox"
                runat="server"
                Width="800px" />
            </div>
       </td>       
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>

       </td>
       <td>
           <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="updatetextbox" AutoPostBack="True" Visible="False"></asp:TextBox>
       </td>
   </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void FormSectionUpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var ctrl = (Control)sender;
   var updatetextbox = (TextBox)ctrl.FindControl("updatetextbox");
   var instructionlistbox = (ListBox)ctrl.FindControl("SectionInstructionListBox");
   updatetextbox.Visible = true;
   updatetextbox.Text = instructionlistbox.SelectedItem.Text;
   FormSectionListView.DataBind();
}
```

I am not doing much in the Page Load currently. I am just hiding the listview on page load, until I select other values.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _connection = DataAccess.SelfRef().GetConnection();

    var list = InstructionDropDown.SelectedValue;
    switch (list)
    {

        case "Form Section":
            FormSectionListBox.DataSourceID = "FormSectionDataSource";
            FormSectionListView.DataBind();
            RenderView(FormSectionListView, "hidden"); // hide listview on page load
            break;

    }

}
```

Comment: There is no textbox with ID UpdateTextBox your aspx is not releavant to your code behind ...

Comment: I'm not seeing a TextBox control with an id="updatetextbox"..am I just not seeing it?

Comment: Nowhere in your front-end code do you have a TextBox control that has its visibility set to false, or have the correct ID called.

Comment: @mybirthname Sorry there was a formatting issue where it wasnt showing on the screen

Comment: @RickS Sorry there was a formatting issue where it wasnt showing on the screen

Comment: @DrewKennedy Sorry there was a formatting issue where it wasnt showing on the screen

Comment: Do you have a page load event?  Please show that code.

Comment: @RickS Uploaded page load code

Comment: Also, I'm not sure you need AutoPostBack=true on your TextBox unless you expect to post back to the server every time you lose focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to make sure you are not rebinding the FormView on Postback.  Everytime you bind the FormView it will reset everything to it's initial state.  Check if it's a post back.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _connection = DataAccess.SelfRef().GetConnection();

    if ( !Page.IsPostBack ) 
    {

        var list = InstructionDropDown.SelectedValue;
        switch (list)
        {

        case "Form Section":
            FormSectionListBox.DataSourceID = "FormSectionDataSource";
            FormSectionListView.DataBind();
           RenderView(FormSectionListView, "hidden"); // hide listview on page load
            break;

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you that was the issue.

Comment: When I check if the Page is PostBack, it seems to interfere with other items on my page because before I manipulate the textbox I use a dropdownList which should automatically show information on the page load.However, it is not doing this anymore.